# no graph has a cut vertex of degree equal to 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is a question from Douglas West introduction to graph theory (2001):

*Let $v$ be a vertex of a connected simple graph $G (V,E)$. Prove that $v$ has a neighbor in every component of G-v. Conclude that no graph has a cut-vertex of degree 1.*

I tried solving the question below, but was a bit unsure about the second part if its really that simple. Please let me know if there is somthing which I can improve upon. Also I'm assuming that the same property holds true for non-simple graphs (includes multiple edges and loops) as well although that's not what I proved here.

We want to show that in every component of $G-v$ the vertex $v$ must be a neighbor and that no graph has a cut-vertex of degree 1.

Proof:

Since $v$ is a cut vertex we know that the number of components, which we denote by $k$ in the graph $G-v$ must be larger than the number of components in $G$. That means that we must have that $k \geq 2$ since $k=1$ for a connected graph. For the connected graph $G$ there must exist a path to all other vertices which means that for the graph $G-v$ it must have paths in $G$ to all other vertices and therefore to all other components of $G-v$. It follows that one can only leave a component of $G-v$ via the vertex $v \in V$ since otherwise we cannot follow a path to the other vertices in the other components. We may then conclude that $v$ must have a neighbor in every component of $G-V$.

For the second part we know that we must have a minimum of $k=2$ components, but such components in $G-v$
when connected in $G$ need to have a degree of at least $2$ thus contradicting the claim that a cut-vertex may have a degree equal to $1$. Since $k \geq 2$ we may conclude that the degree must be larger or equal to $2$ and we write $deg(v) \geq 2$ where $v$ is a vertex in $G$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: The second part of the question is a bit weird. I think the author wants the reader to show that it’s a consequence of the first part, but that’s not necessary. Say $v$ is a cut-vertex of a graph $G$, and $C_1$, $C_2$ are two (among possibly others) components of $G  - v$ (that result from the deletion of $v$). The problem is that if deg$(v) = 1$, then either $C_1$ or $C_2$ would not be there to begin with.

Comment: As for the first part, I think a cleaner argument could be as follows. Assume for a contradiction that there exists a component $C$ of $G - v$ in which $v$ has no neighbors. Then in $G$, there is no edges between $C$ and $G - C$. Hence $G$ is not connected, a contradiction.

Comment: @ensbana Your argumentation for the both parts makes a lot of sense thanks. Can I ask when you are using proof by contradiction method how do you assure yourself that you don't end up in a scenario where the contradiction has nothing to do with the initial assumption and you have employed it correctly? Is it just something that comes with experience?

Comment: Could you give an example of the scenario?

Comment: @ensbana I wasn't really thinking of a specific scenario, but we could use the question you answered as an example. How did you go about choosing which proof to use for example?